# Iterate list inside list inside list java

Tags: java, list

I got a question. Is there a simple solution to iterate over the list that is inside of a list and inside of a list again? 
So my point is I have few of lists inside of each other (based on xml unmarshall) and I sometimes do not know how deep is the structure.

Exsample:

```
class Car{
 private List<Door>
 }

class Door{
 private List<Parts>
 }
class Parts{
 private List<Some1>
 }
 }
class Some1{
 private List<Some2>
 }
```

So how can iterate from Car to Some2 without knowing if there is a list or is empty in a "good way"? I mean without 5-times nested "for" loops mixed up with another 6 "if's".

Comment: Create a method within each class that iterates over their respective lists.  It keeps things decoupled, makes it easier to handle errors, and is overall cleaner.

Comment: DeeV has an good idea. In the end, you're ultimately doing nested loops anyways under the hood, but at least that type of method can help clean things up.

Comment: You need recursion and you're not gonna like it.

Comment: In this exaplme - good idea. But I also have in one place something like:Class Some1{
 private List<Some1>
 }
So basically a class that point to each selfe. Not a very brilliant solution but not to avoid I am affraid... How to handle that with iteration?

Answer (score 1):

DeeV makes a good suggestion about each class iterating over their respective lists.

As a client using the Car class, you may want to get all the Some2s that it contains. If you do this:

```
car.getDoors().getParts().get...
```

you expose the internals of the Car class. A much cleaner solution would be to have the following method in the Car class:

```
public List<Some2> getSome2s()
```

This way, if the internals of Car change (perhaps using a different Collection type) your client code will not break as long as a list of Some2s is still returned.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easier way than nested for loops. If you want more speed try using different structures like Maps.

Answer (score 0):

First implement composite pattern with your classes after you'll be able to recursive to leafs and aggregate them in a list.